# Question about the furthest points in a convex hull (in java)

Tags: java

I am trying to find the furthest point of a convex hull. I used the jarvis to find the convex hull. Then I stored my points in a array list.

Now I am trying to figure out which ones are the most distant. My idea is to pick a point set it a start and pick another pick point and set it as far. Then go across all the points until I find one that is more far, and then set that one to start.

I know there is something called rotating calipers but I do not not understand it. Is there a simple way and code online (in java) that show you how to find the diameter of convex hull.

```
//now we create the object which let use the convex hull method
        Jarvis2 jav=new Jarvis2();
    List<Point> hull=new ArrayList<>();
     hull=jav.findConvex(list);
     System.out.println("__________________________");
     //print out the points on the hull
         for(int i=0;i<hull.size();i++)
        {

         System.out.println(hull.get(i).x+ " " + hull.get(i).y+ " ");

        }




     Point start=hull.get(0);
     Point far=hull.get(1);
     Point temp;

    // double dist=jav.distance(start,far);
     //System.out.println(dist);
     int r=0;
    while(r<1000)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<hull.size();i++)
        {
            if(start.equals(hull.get(i)))
            {
             continue;


            }

            if( jav.distance(start,far) < jav.distance(start,hull.get(i)))
            {
                far=hull.get(i);


            }
        }

            temp=start;
            start=far;
            far=temp;

            //find a way to break it
            r++;

    }



     System.out.println("_________________");
     System.out.println("the furthest points are ");
    System.out.println(start.x+" "+start.y);
    System.out.println(far.x+ "   " + far.y);
```

Comment: When you did a **web search** for [`rotating calipers`](https://www.google.com/search?q=rotating+calipers), didn't that lead to the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) that includes pseudo-code?

Comment: I just do not get what rotating calipers is....

Comment: Do you know what a [caliper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calipers) is? Now think about using that on an object that isn't round, so that when you turn it (aka *rotate* it), the tips will move further apart and then closer together, as the "width" of the object changes depending on the angle. Whether you turn the object or the caliper doesn't really matter. The effect is the same.